# Python Docker SDK inside container

Tags: python, docker

Im wondering if there is a way to use Python Docker SKD:

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#docker-sdk-for-python

inside a container and still be able to menage outside containers.
I mean that there is a single python container with Docker SDK used in some script which runs along which other containers on some host and menages them.

By default SDK is probably calling `localhost` to connect to docker so maybe some routing inside container will do?

Comment: You want to manage the Docker engine from inside a Docker container running in that docker engine?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to manage few Docker containers from another docker container running on same hosts alongside

Comment: You can bind the host Docker socket to the container by running: `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock $IMAGE_NAME`. After that you can install Docker inside the container and manage the other containers in the CLI level, should work on Python as well. 
Does that workout for you?

Comment: It does! That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by @SimpleNiko

This is the solution:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock $IMAGE_NAME
```

or from docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Remember that anyone who can access this socket file can pretty trivially root the entire host, so be very careful with basic security things in your application.  (Don't construct `docker run` commands by concatenating strings, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer checked works, just to add a container name will be like this:

```
docker run --name CONTAINER_NAME -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock image_name
```

If the image have a version like happened to me:

```
docker run --name CONTAINER_NAME -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock image_name:1.0.0
```